# Defining a struct parameter with the type of the struct itself

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, forward-declaration

I'm trying to launch a BFS algorithm into a Matrix to get the shortest path from my position to the first accessible element that the BFS finds. Matrix is composed by nodes defined as follow:

```
    struct node {
    int distance = -1;
    node parent;
    Pos position;
    //Direction to get into the actual node from the parent's position.
    Dir direction;
    Cell cell;
 };
```

I need to have an instance of the parent node (the one previously visited and with less distance to the initial node that the actual node) to trace the fastest path back to the original node once the desired item is found. But it seems that *node parent;* declaration throws an error, so it is possible to declare an element of the struct with the type of the struct itself? or do i have to declare it as a pointer to the element?

Here you have the errors:

```
error: field has incomplete type 'node' 
       node parent;
            ^
note: definition of 'node' is not complete until the closing '} 
      struct node {
             ^
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use a pointer. A node cannot contain another node object, because that node itself would contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, which would itself contain another node, and so on.

Comment: If you could do this - have a structure include itself - think about how you could compute the size of such a structure and what that implies....

Comment: Pick _one_ language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. A struct can't contain an instance of itself.

C++ (and C) have value semantics. Perhaps you are using a mental model of a different language, in which `parent` would mean a reference to an object stored elsewhere.

But in C++, `node parent;` means an object called `parent` which is fully stored inside the outer object. So your code would lead to an infinite 'depth' of objects.

Based on your description, you probably mean to *refer to* another node which is actually stored elsewhere. In C you would write `node *parent;`, and then be very careful. In C++ you have a few options, including `weak_ptr<node> parent;` .

In both languages cases, a non-intrusive container is another option (i.e. your nodes do not contain any node reference; and you have another structure which holds all the information about node links).

Answer (score 0):

> it is possible to declare an element of the struct with the type of the struct itself?

No.

You cannot define something in terms of itself.

What if cars always contained an exact copy of themselves? Would that work? No! It would not fit.

How big would it be? The size of the car would be the sum of the size of its wheels, seats, steering wheel and, er, another car... with its wheels, seats, steering wheel and, er, another car... hmm...